# How to generate Optional<Class<?>> in JCodeModel?

Tags: generics, reflection, nested-generics, sun-codemodel, jcodemodel

I want to create JCodeModel for the below method:

```
private static Optional<Class<?>> getTypeOfId(String fieldName) {
        switch (fieldName.toLowerCase()) {
            case "IDFORCLASSX":
            {
                return Optional.of(X.class);
            }
            default:
            {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am presently  using below code for creating the return type of the class.

```
AbstractJClass optionalOfClassType = codeModel.ref(Optional.class)
 .narrow(codeModel.ref(Class.class)
 .narrow(codeModel.ref("?")));
```

But the above code gives a high priority FindBug error `PRMC_POSSIBLY_REDUNDANT_METHOD_CALLS`.

Can anyone help me to optimize the above line of code?

Comment: What does the generated code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines:

```
codeModel
    .ref(Optional.class)
    .narrow(
        codeModel.ref(Class.class).narrow(
            codeModel.ref(Object.class).wildcard()));
```